# Elastic Search on a rackspace instance

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have installed Elasticsearch on a rackspace instance (similar to EC2 cloud instance). The instance has two IP's. One public facing one and one private eth0 ip. I have installed kibana and logstash also in the same instance.

So, when I try to view kibana using the public facing IP I get the error message that the ES instance is not reachable. Also when i try to issue  the connection times out.

But when I ssh to the instance and issue a curl on  I get the correct json for ES. Am wondering how to link the public facing IP to this elastic search so that I can view my kibana dashboard.

Note: I tried to edit the config.js in Kibana to point the ES to . But still no effect.

Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Sounds like a CORS issue.  Have you tried enabling it?  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Comment: Yes, I have enabled. The elastic search is not reachable from public IP. Even though I have installed kibana and try to connect kibana to the ES using private IP, it still fails.